# If at least one input is checked, toggleClass to his ancestor sibling - JQuery

Tags: jquery

Having multiple `.ancestor` elements with this structure

```
<div class="ancestor">
    <div class="parent-1"></div>
    <div class="parent-2">
        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using JQuery can I add a class to `.parent-1` if at least one checkbox inside `.checkbox-group` is checked, and remove it if all of them are then unchecked?

I came up with this

```
if ($('.checkbox-group input:checked').length > 0 ) {
    $(this).closest('.parent-2').siblings('.parent-1').toggleClass("active");
}
```

But I guess I am doing it wrong

Comment: `this` belongs to what?

Comment: if length>0 ... toggle?  Means each time you call it, it will switch back and forth.   Use the [overload](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) to set/clear:   `..toggle("active", $('.checkbox-group input:checked').length > 0)` (no `if`)

Comment: As first comment: need to know when your code is running. On startup? On submit? on input change?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm running the script on .click() of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:has()` Selector

https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```js
$('.parent-2:has(.checkbox-group input:checked)')
  .siblings('.parent-1')
  .toggleClass('active')
```

```css
.active { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="parent-1">state</div>
  <div class="parent-2">
    <div class="checkbox-group">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```